# How to groupby different keys in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, group-by, key

I have an array of object which the keys are the page and link, I want the final result to group the page by links.

My code is :

```
  let Test =[
    {page:'getting link 1', lien:['lienPage1HTTP_404V']}, 
    {page:'getting link 2', lien:['lienPage2HTTP_404V1']},
    {page:'getting link 3', lien:['lienPage3HTTP_404V3','lienPage3HTTP_404V']},
    {page:'getting link 4', lien:['lienPage4HTTP_404V4']},
  ];

  var sorted = {};
  var Last1 =[];
  var Last2 =[];

  for( var i = 0; i< Test.length;  i++ ){
    if(Test[i].lien.length>1){
      for(let k=0; k<Test[i].lien.length; k++){
        Last1.push(({lien:Test[i].lien[k], page: Test[i].page}))
      }
    } 
    else {
      Last2.push(Test[i])
    }
  }
  var Last = Last1.concat(Last2);
  for( var i = 0; i< Last.length;  i++ ){
    if( sorted[Last[i].lien] == undefined ){
      sorted[Last[i].lien] = [];
    }
    sorted[Last[i].lien].push(Last[i].page)
  }
```

when I try to console the `sorted`, I get :

```
[object Object] {
  lienPage1HTTP_404V: ["getting link 1"],
  lienPage2HTTP_404V1: ["getting link 2"],
  lienPage3HTTP_404V: ["getting link 3"],
  lienPage3HTTP_404V3: ["getting link 3"],
  lienPage4HTTP_404V4: ["getting link 4"]
}
```

But I want the final result will be :

```
[object Object] {
  lienPage1HTTP_404V: ["getting link 1", "getting link 3"],
  lienPage2HTTP_404V1: ["getting link 2"],
  lienPage3HTTP_404V3: ["getting link 3"],
  lienPage4HTTP_404V4: ["getting link 4"]
}
```

For each same key, we have the array of his value.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: lienPage1HTTP_404V and lienPage3HTTP_404V has different key names, that could be problem also (Page1 -> Page3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could only take a part of the strings of `lien` and get only `HTTP_404V'` for grouping in a temporary object.

```js
var data = [{ page: 'getting link 1', lien: ['lienPage1HTTP_404V'] }, { page: 'getting link 2', lien: ['lienPage2HTTP_404V1'] }, { page: 'getting link 3', lien: ['lienPage3HTTP_404V3', 'lienPage3HTTP_404V'] }, { page: 'getting link 4', lien: ['lienPage4HTTP_404V4'] }],
    reference = {},
    grouped = {};

for (let { page, lien } of data) {
    for (let k of lien) {
        let key = k.match(/HTTP_404.*/)[0];
        if (!reference[key]) {
            reference[key] = [];
            grouped[k] = reference[key];
        }
        reference[key].push(page);
    }
}

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It works well, thank you, but when I have multiple keys as 'lienPage1HTTP_404V258' and I get it from the backend, how can I replace 9 for the slice ?

Comment: what should happen with this key?

Comment: It should referenced for the string which having `HTTP_404`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the unnecessary part of the text and work with the remaining part.  Additionally, you should keep a pointers of the grouped values.

```js
let arr =[{page:'getting link 1', lien:['lienPage1HTTP_404V']}, {page:'getting link 2', lien:['lienPage2HTTP_404V1']},{page:'getting link 3', lien:['lienPage3HTTP_404V3','lienPage3HTTP_404V']},{page:'getting link 4', lien:['lienPage4HTTP_404V4']}],
    result = arr.reduce((a, {page, lien}) => {
      lien.forEach(e => {
        let extractedPart = e.replace(/lienPage[0-9]+/, "");
        a.pointers[extractedPart] = a.pointers[extractedPart] || e;
        (a.group[a.pointers[extractedPart]] || (a.group[a.pointers[extractedPart]] = [])).push(page);
      });
      return a;
    }, {pointers: {}, group: {}}).group;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newAr = []
Test.forEach((a,b)=>{newAr.push(a.lien)})
console.log(newAr.filter((a, b) => newAr.indexOf(a) === b))
//["lienPage1HTTP_404V,lienPage2HTTP_404V1,lienPage3HTTP_404V3,lienPage3HTTP_404V,lienPage4HTTP_404V4"]
```

//Use this unique array and loop through Test Object

Use Map of Object and loop through newAr and append to the Object as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This can help:

```
let Test =[
    {page:'getting link 1', lien:['lienPage1HTTP_404V']}, 
    {page:'getting link 2', lien:['lienPage2HTTP_404V1']},
    {page:'getting link 3', lien:['lienPage3HTTP_404V3','lienPage3HTTP_404V']},
    {page:'getting link 4', lien:['lienPage4HTTP_404V4']},
  ];
var data={};

  Test.map(el=>{
      el.lien.map(dt=>{
          data[dt]=data[dt]?[...data[dt],el.page]:[el.page]
      })
  })
  console.log(data)
```